# linq select all from group by

Tags: c#, linq

if i don't want to specified field one by one but i want to select all field without  specified. how am i going to do it?

```
List<test> xxx = new List<test>();
            var rows = xxx.Where(s => s.test1 == "")
                .GroupBy(s => s.test1)
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    test1 = s.First().test1,
                    test2 = s.First().test2
                })
                .ToList();
```

i dont want to use var rows = from s in xxx bla bla lba select s. but using above method. how to i do it?

Regards,
MH

Comment: `Select(s => s.First())`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. The above example will only ever produce a single group, since it will only deal with s.test1=="" compliant instances. Can you show you want the type of "rows" variable to be? As well as the class definition of "test"?

Comment: Do you think you could provide a sample dataset to demonstrate what you would like the result to look like? It might help because the questions is hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't really want a `GroupBy()` at all, and what you really want is this:

```
List<test> xxx = new List<test>();
var row = xxx.First(s => s.test1 == "");
```

Comment: you are right .....  i think if i use like tat, better remove group by. thanks again haha...

Answer (score 0):

```
List<test> xxx = new List<test>();
var rows = xxx.Where(s => s.test1 == "")
.GroupBy(s => s.test1).ToList();
```

not really sure what u want to achieve. but do you mean like this?

Comment: Ya I am confused why he would want to perform a group by then take the top 1 from each list. I'm sure it would make more sense with some context.

Comment: @FeistyMango It's quite common scenario. However, most likely you also want to sort each group first, before taking the first one.

Comment: That is what I was driving at I suppose. The list isn't sorted ... soo ... top 1 of .. whatever that group by decides to bring back seems like it would yield some interesting results.

Answer (score 0):

Select items by group

```
    IEnumerable<DataRow> sequence = DataTbl.AsEnumerable();

    var GroupedData = from d in sequence group d by d["panelName"];      // GroupedData is now of type IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Document>>

    foreach (var GroupList in GroupedData) // GroupList = "document group", of type IGrouping<int, Document>
    {
      string GroupName = "";
      foreach (var Item in GroupList)
      {
        GroupName = Item["panelName"].ToString();

        string ItemReference = Item["reference"].ToString();
      }
    }
```